# Domain redirecting to domain with home directory

Tags: redirect, cpanel

one of my customer having an issue with domain redirect. The domain is redirecting from http://domainname.com to http://domainname.com/~USERNAME/
its an cPanel server and he is using Zencart.  I have checked cPanel redirect option but didn't see any redirection set for it. Can somebody help me on this.

Comment: What in /home/<user>/public_html or path for domainname.com .htaccess? It's your domain installed a zencart with Installatron or other Auto-Installer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed zencart on your domain with the temp URL and due to that site link are redirecting to such URL, You will have to change your site pages URL in your databases.